# Unable to produce forest plot

Tags: r, r-forestplot

using the code below seem to get the error message

```
Error: unexpected ',' in " graphwidth = 'auto',"
```

```js
library(forestplot)

    names <- c('Study Name and Year', Dennekemp et al 2010', 'Silverman et al 2010', 'Ensor et al 2013', 'Rosenthal et al 2013', 'Wichmann et al 2013', 'Razar et al 2014', 'Straney et al 2014', 'Dennkamp et al 2015', 'Kang et al 2015', 'Haikerwal et al 2015', 'Xia et al 2017', 'Jones et al 2020', 'Kim et al 2020', 'Kojima et al 2020', 'Wang et al 2020', 'Fu-JU Cheng et al 2021', 'Kojima et al 2021')
    
    coef2 <- c(1.09, 1.04, 1.046, 1.09, 1.1, 1, 1.02, 1.07, 1.01, 1.07, 1.07, 1.017, 1.0159, 0.016, 0.0112, 1.013, 1.02)
    high2 <-c(1.15,1.08,1.082,1.2, 1.2, 1.07, 1.03, 1.15, 1.02, 1.13, 1.1,  0.213, 1.0166, 0.031, 0.0123, 1.0241, 1.06)
    low2 <-c(1.03, 0.99, 1.012, 0.99, 1, 0.93, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.01, 0.018, 1.0151, 0.01, 0.0102, 1.002, 0.99)
             
    boxsize2 <- c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)
    fordata <- data.frame(coef=coef2, low=low2,high=high2,           boxsize=boxsize2)
    fordata <- rbind(NA,  fordata)
    
    row_names <-cbind(names, c(  '1.09 [1.03-1.15]', '1.04 [0.99-1.08]','1.046 [1.012-1.082]','1.09 [0.99-1.20]','1.1 [1.00-1.20]','1.00 [0.93-1.07]','1.02 [1.00-1.03]','1.07 [1.00-1.15]','1.01 [1.00-1.02]','1.07 [1.01-1.13]','1.07 [1.04-1.10]','1.017 [0.018-0.213]','1.0159 [1.0151-1.0166]','0.016 [0.01-0.031]','0.0112 [0.0102-0.0123]','1.013 [1.002-1.0241]','1.02 [0.99 –1.06]')
    
    
    forestplot(labeltext = row_names,
               mean = fordata$coef,
               upper = fordata$high,
               lower = fordata$low,
               is.summary=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
               boxsize = fordata$boxsize,
               zero = 1,
               xlog = FALSE,
               xlab = "RR (95% CI)",
               col = fpColors(lines="black", box="black"),
               ci.vertices = TRUE,
               xticks = NULL,
               colgap = unit(0.03,'npc'),
               hrzl_lines= TRUE,
               lineheight = unit(1.1,"cm"),
               graphwidth = 'auto',
               txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label = gpar(cex = 0.8),
                              title = gpar(cex = 1),
                              ticks = gpar(cex = 0.7),
                              xlab = gpar(cex = 0.7))
```

Attempted to correct it multiple times to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a few issues with the code - missing apostrophes and closed brackets.

This should fix it:

```r
library(forestplot)

names <- c('Study Name and Year', 'Dennekemp et al 2010', 'Silverman et al 2010', 'Ensor et al 2013', 'Rosenthal et al 2013', 'Wichmann et al 2013', 'Razar et al 2014', 'Straney et al 2014', 'Dennkamp et al 2015', 'Kang et al 2015', 'Haikerwal et al 2015', 'Xia et al 2017', 'Jones et al 2020', 'Kim et al 2020', 'Kojima et al 2020', 'Wang et al 2020', 'Fu-JU Cheng et al 2021', 'Kojima et al 2021')

coef2 <- c(1.09, 1.04, 1.046, 1.09, 1.1, 1, 1.02, 1.07, 1.01, 1.07, 1.07, 1.017, 1.0159, 0.016, 0.0112, 1.013, 1.02)
high2 <- c(1.15,1.08,1.082,1.2, 1.2, 1.07, 1.03, 1.15, 1.02, 1.13, 1.1,  0.213, 1.0166, 0.031, 0.0123, 1.0241, 1.06)
low2 <- c(1.03, 0.99, 1.012, 0.99, 1, 0.93, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.01, 0.018, 1.0151, 0.01, 0.0102, 1.002, 0.99)

boxsize2 <- c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)
fordata <- data.frame(coef=coef2, low=low2,high=high2, boxsize=boxsize2)
fordata <- rbind(NA, fordata)

row_names <- cbind(names, c(  '1.09 [1.03-1.15]', '1.04 [0.99-1.08]','1.046 [1.012-1.082]','1.09 [0.99-1.20]','1.1 [1.00-1.20]','1.00 [0.93-1.07]','1.02 [1.00-1.03]','1.07 [1.00-1.15]','1.01 [1.00-1.02]','1.07 [1.01-1.13]','1.07 [1.04-1.10]','1.017 [0.018-0.213]','1.0159 [1.0151-1.0166]','0.016 [0.01-0.031]','0.0112 [0.0102-0.0123]','1.013 [1.002-1.0241]','1.02 [0.99 –1.06]'))

forestplot(labeltext = row_names,
           mean = fordata$coef,
           upper = fordata$high,
           lower = fordata$low,
           is.summary=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
           boxsize = fordata$boxsize,
           zero = 1,
           xlog = FALSE,
           xlab = "RR (95% CI)",
           col = fpColors(lines="black", box="black"),
           ci.vertices = TRUE,
           xticks = NULL,
           colgap = unit(0.03,"npc"),
           hrzl_lines= TRUE,
           lineheight = unit(1.1,"cm"),
           graphwidth = 'auto',
           txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label = gpar(cex = 0.8),
                          title = gpar(cex = 1),
                          ticks = gpar(cex = 0.7),
                          xlab = gpar(cex = 0.7)))
```

However there is now a new error for which I am not sure